# show event in jquery context menu not working

Tags: jquery, contextmenu

I want to show and hide some option of context menu before its show. So I use `show` `event` mention on [documentation](http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/). But it is not working for me. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EGNSw/116/)

```
show:function(){
        alert(0)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well all the options are just javascript objects. So on $(document).ready you can can modify the options collections to suit your needs. Here is an example where i modify the options:

```
$(function () {
    var menuItems = {};

    function somelogic() {
        alert('hi');
        return true;
    }

    if (somelogic()) {
        menuItems = {
            "edit": { name: "Edit", icon: "edit" },
            "cut": { name: "Cut", icon: "cut" },
            "copy": { name: "Copy This to the Clipboard Please", icon: "copy" },
            "paste": { name: "Paste", icon: "paste" },
            "delete": { name: "Delete", icon: "delete" },
            "submenu": {
                name: "Submenu",
                items: {
                    "submenu_item1": {
                        // NOTE: this is the item that wraps in IE9 but not in Firefox
                        name: "Change Reporting Interval"
                    },
                    "submenu_item2": {
                        name: "Item 2"
                    }
                }
            },
            "quit": { name: "Quit", icon: "quit" }
        }
    }



    $.contextMenu({
        selector: '.context-menu-one',
        callback: function (key, options) {
            var m = "clicked: " + key;
            window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m);
        },
        items: menuItems
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is nice one. But I wanted know is there any method to get the list of items before its open